# Santa Clarita Diet cancelled and open plots

Tags: cancellation, santa-clarita-diet

*Santa Clarita Diet* was cancelled leaving many open storylines.

**Did the creators comment at all on the open storylines?**

Such as:

- What was the virus or where did it come from?
- What was Mr. Legs?
- Did Joel become a walking Mr. Legs?

Comment: "Did the creators comment on what was meant to happen if the show didn't get cancelled" is *not* banal trivia and sounds like a perfectly on-topic question to me.

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm rather new to this SE but seeing as it's getting downvotes, I'd be interested in making the question answerable. Cheers

Comment: If anything, I would have thought this would be too broad, as you're technically asking four questions (although the latter three all come under your main question). I'm afraid I don't know why people are voting to close as trivia, but hopefully one of the close-voters will be willing to explain.